# using one layout for lots of data to show it in different screens

Tags: android, android-intent

I am planning to create an qwiz app for kids.

The main activity should contain the base components of specific information, each component button should hold a lot of items, each item should have a lot of attributes (text view, imageView, sounds, animations, cases to choose etc..).

My question is, should I create a layout for each item that hold the specific attributes, meaning it needs hundreds of layouts?

The important question: when user clicks on any component button that is holding the qwiz items, how can I show every item in a different screen with its attributes and move to second item screens gradually by clicking next? What code should I use to make this Process (showing each data item in different screen)? It's similar to the Duolingo process.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to provide an example so we can help you solve a specific problem.

Comment: If you have similar object structure, you can use the `Serializable` class to pass the object into the `Intent` which will allow you to use same `Activity` and reuse the **layout** for different click with different data.